# AppStoreでのアプリ配布について

Tags: monaca

アプリを作成してようやくリリースできそうな段階まで来ました。
[Monacaの公式ドキュメント](https://docs.monaca.io/ja/manual/deploy/appstore/itunes_connect/#publishing-the-app)では「レビューには、2 週間ほど、通常かかります。」と書かれていますが、
最近はアプリの審査期間が短くなっていて、2日以内に審査が通るという話を
ネットの記事などで見たことがあります。

件の記事が出た2016年5月以降、Monacaのアプリを申請してからリリースするまで
実際にどのくらいの時間がかかるのでしょうか？

Comment: 皆さまご回答ありがとうございました。
大体1～2日で申請が通るようですね。
良く考えたらMonacaかどうかは関係ありませんでした。
今度試しにアプリの申請をしてみます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://appreviewtimes.com/

こちらのサイトに現在申請してから審査に通るまでの平均期間の目安を
Twitterのハッシュタグでツイートされたものから算出しているサイトが有るみたいです。

Comment: 私もこのサイトを利用していますが結構正確です。先日も2日程度で審査通ってます。また、あくまで目安です。リジェクト等発生する可能性もありますし、レビュー用動画を作成していなければレビューに時間がかかる可能性もあります。

Answer (score 1):

現状のAppleStoreの審査についてです。

レビュー開始までは非常に早くなりました。
日本時間23時～翌12時までにレビューになることが多く、
最短で提出後、30分後にレビュー状態になることもありました。
※2週間というのはレビュー状態までにかかる時間で、
さらにレビュー完了までに時間がかかるケースもありました。
レビュー時間そのものはこれまでと変わらないと思います。
※30分～時間がかかる時は1日。

Monacaであるかは関係なく(どの環境においてもXcodeあるいはApple Loaderで提出)ですので、
一度試しにだしてみると良いかと思います。

※新規アプリは不明です、アプリ更新時は上記時間でした。

一部言い回しに誤解が発生しそうだったので訂正しました。